# IOS 13.3 - it refreshes the pages when clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, ios, ios13, react-boilerplate

need help.

I'am using react boiler plate to create pages, just a problem, in IOS 13.3 (iphone), it refreshes the pages when clicking the back button.

I need to retain the pages when clicking the back button without refreshing the page.

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently navigation the user in your app? If you are using direct links this will happen. Implement history.push() and use that to navigate the user by changing your state accordingly

Comment: will try that. thanks.

Comment: not working sir

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: the history.push()